# 500 error after Controller return statement

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring as my mvc framework, and I am getting a 500 error from one of my controllers.  However, I have debugged this error and found that the 500 error is thrown AFTER the controller return statement, so no errors are thrown server-side.  I am returning a Map where the Object is a custom class.  Jackson is imported correctly, and this custom class has a toString method (not sure if this is necessary).  Also, this same style of controller return works for other methods.  I am unsure why the 500 error is thrown.  Code snippet is below.  Thanks!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> method(){
    HashMap<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<>();
    Result result = service.method();
    retMap.put("result", result);
    return retMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured out this problem.  My Result class was defined in another project, that was imported through maven.  Apparently Jackson does not pick up classes from other imported projects, so I created a DTO class in my web project, and converted to this DTO before returning it in the controller.  Now it works perfectly!

EDIT: Does anyone know how to get Jackson to scan classes from imported projects?